# Is there a way to revert my .java file file association

Tags: eclipse, file-association

I am trying to return my .java file back to the way it was before.
I ended up opening my java file by opening with notepad and now all my java files are opening from notepad, which I don't want. Although I can still drag my java files into eclipse even though the file is opened in notepad, I want to know if it's possible to change it back to the default file it was before.

Before all my .java files look like this
[image]

Now it looks like this: 
[image]

Is it possible to fix this?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LPE7.jpg):

Comment: The title of your question suggests you want to repair a damaged .java file. Yet the text suggests you want to restore "Eclipse" as the default editor for .java files. These are two different things.

I'm going to answer the text of your question, but I suggest editing the title to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the text of the question (as of 12/01/2019) you appear to want to restore "Eclipse" as the default editor for .java files.

This is an operating system specific task, so it will depend on the system you are running. Because you mentioned "Notepad", I'll assume you are on Windows. In recent (and fairly old) versions of Windows, the following should work:

1. Right-click on a .java file.
2. From the contextual menu, choose "Open with..." | "Choose another app"
3. Check the box for "Always use this app to open .java files"
4. Click "More apps" and scroll down to find Eclipse... If you don't find it, scroll to the bottom where you can search for it.

Once you open the .java file with this method, Eclipse will be the default editor. You could also find "Default apps" in settings and set it manually.

If you aren't on Windows, just do a search for "How do I set default apps on ", or add details to your question here.

Good luck.

Comment: Based on the screenshots the author is using Windows.

Comment: Hi,

i actually did a system restore and somehow it returned back to the way it was before. Thanks for the response